# Escape Reserved Words for win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I am using the win32com library for Python and cannot figure out how to escape Python reserved words that are used in MAPI for Outlook.  For example, if I try and execute the following code I will get a syntax error because I am using the word 'class'.

```
import win32com.client


recipient = 'John Smith'
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
recipient = namespace.createRecipient(recipient)
resolved = recipient.Resolve()
sharedCalendar = namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9)

appointments = sharedCalendar.Items

for i in range(len(appointments)):

    print appointments[i].class
```

I have tried using class_ and a few other modifications but still no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving in the question.

Comment: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

And it points to this line "print appointments[i].class"

Comment: Did you try `print dir(appointments[i])` to look for names?

Comment: 'class' should be an acceptable member according to the docs.  I have used almost every other member in this list and I am able to get data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_members.aspx

Comment: If I print the dir() option, I get a list of methods (e.g. '_proc_','_unicode_to_string_').  And when I apply any method to appointments[i] (and print it), I get '<bound method CDispatch.(method) of <COMObject <unknown>>>'

Comment: How about `getattr(appointments[i], 'class')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(appointments)):
    print appointments[i].Class
```

Or as [kratenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245455/escape-reserved-words-for-win32com/30245964#comment48592703_30245455) suggested:

```
for i in range(len(appointments)):
    print getattr(appointments[i], 'class')
```

Comment: The proper way to gain access to a dynamically resolved method (as is the case with most methods of a COM object) that is a reserved Python keyword is via getattr (see comment to question for what this looks like). The solution probably worked because win32com does case-insensitive lookup.

Comment: @Schollii: The proper case is `Class`, so just using `appointments[i].Class` is a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: @gabe if that's the case (sorry for the pun!) then solution valid, but if OP had indeed needed reserved keyword then getattr would be way to go.